# Join dict to string

Tags: julia

How would in join a dictionary in Julia similar to like what one of the Python ways is:

```py
 diction = {"DC": 4,
           "NH": 1,
           "MI": 36,
           "MO": 4989,
           "FL": 157,
           "UT": 13,
           "NV": 9,
           "CA": 110,
           "WV": 6,
           "NY": 39,
           "ME": 1,
           "SC": 26,
           "KY": 71}
stri = ' | '.join(map(lambda x: '%2.2s %5.5s' % (str(x[0]), str(x[1])), diction.items()))
```

What I have come up with:

```
diction = Dict(["DC" => 4
                "NH" => 1,
                "MI" => 36,
                "MO" => 4989,
                "FL" => 157,
                "UT" => 13,
                "NV" => 9,
                "CA" => 110,
                "WV" => 6,
                "NY" => 39,
                "ME" => 1,
                "SC" => 26,
                "KY" => 71])
stri = [@sprintf("%2.2s %5.5s | ",st,ct) for st,ct in keys(diction),values(diction)]
```

Yields:

```
ERROR: syntax: invalid iteration specification
```

OUTPUT:

```
DC    4 | NH    1 | MI    36 | MO    4989 | FL    157 | UT    13 | NV    9 | CA    110 | WV    6 | NY    39 | ME    1 | SC    26 | KY    71
```

Comment: Could you include the output you expect? Not everybody speaks python.

Comment: @IanBush updated question. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent Julia versions, you need to pull in the sprintf macros with "using Printf". In addition, when you iterate a dictionary, you need to wrap the key-value pair in parentheses `(st, ct)` (which Python does not require; this also applies to enumerated for loops). In addition, you should still use a `join` here, or the line will end with your '|' separator.

This then becomes:

```
using Printf
diction = Dict(["DC" => 4,
            "NH" => 1,
            "MI" => 36,
            "MO" => 4989,
            "FL" => 157,
            "UT" => 13,
            "NV" => 9,
            "CA" => 110,
            "WV" => 6,
            "NY" => 39,
            "ME" => 1,
            "SC" => 26,
            "KY" => 71])
stri = join([@sprintf("%2.2s %5.5s", st, string(ct)) for (st,ct) in diction], " | ")
println(stri)
```